# Magnetic field strength and current flow in a surface

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, electric-current

Consider the case where there is a magnetic field source, some distance, $r$, away from a metallic surface. At the surface the magnetic field will have some strength, $B_0$.

Does anyone know of any law or relation that describes the effect of a magnetic field on the flow, or behaviour, of current in the surface of a metal? In particular I am interested in the case for when the source of the magnetic field is supplied by an alternating current with some frequency $\omega$.

Comment: Try looking at the Hall effect, for the steady-state case. For other cases, since a magnetic field from an oscillating source is just a standard electromagnetic wave, the metal would behave identically to a metal surface with incident light on it.

Comment: @probably_someone I looked into it as you suggested. However, the hall effect only applies for when a current is being put through the medium. In the case I am interested in, the only current that is flowing are the Eddy currents induced by the magnetic field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A time varying magnetic field induces a "Eddy Current" in a nearby conductor in accordance with Maxwell's Equations, Faraday's Law where $dB/dt$ gives a (time varying) $E$ field.

For high conductivity metals, typical electrical equipment values of $B$ the Eddy Current linearly superimposes with any other current in the conductor from any other potentials in circuit with the conductor.

The Eddy Current creates its own time varying $E$ field opposing the external field causing the Eddy current.
In the limit of a superconductor the external magnetic field appears to be reflected by the conductor.

There is a secondary effect from the Lorentz force: [Geometrical magnetoresistance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetoresistance),
which is very small for high conductivity metals.

Comment: This answer seems much more applicable to my scenario.  But do you know of any relations that explicitly relates the strength of the magnetic field to the size of the induced Eddy currents. That is what I am really interested in.

Comment: it becomes complicated to do calcs for arbitrary geometries but the general problem is a staple of 2nd undergrad or higher EM courses with some solutions for sufficiently simple geometries, symmetries - Numerical solvers are well developed, but often expensive tools aimed at Electrical Engineering applications